# Schema of categories (Schema.org) Blogposting

Tags: schema, categories

Good day! I've been looking for the schema for my categories, but there is nothing looks like that. How can I use schema for the categories on my blog? My code:

```xml
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <div class="article" itemprop="articleBody">
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="categories">
        <a href="">1st category</a>
        <a href="">2nd category</a>
        ....
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking here and what it has to do with programming?

Comment: have you visited schema.org?

Comment: You have to indent code blocks, or select them and press Ctrl-K (or the "Code Sample" button labelled `{}`).

Comment: Guys. I'm talking about the microdata for the categories of my blog